# Where should I place setting.xml file if I create setting.xml file locally instaed of jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins

Where should I place settings.xml config file if i am creating in locally and what should be the content on if I am adding server id and credentials

[image]

Comment: The `settings.xml` in Jenkins should be handled via the config file provider plugin https://plugins.jenkins.io/config-file-provider/

Comment: @khmarbaise Hi I have mentioned that I want to do the same in local with out jenkins.

Comment: The `settings.xml` belongs to `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml` ...

Comment: @SAINATHREDDYBONTHU What is the reason for using a local `settings.xml`?

Comment: You tagged the question as maven and jenkins related, but don't expect every stackoverflow user to pay attention to those tags. State cleary in the question that you're asking about maven. It seems you're trying to insert an image but it doesn't show up unless you click.